# How to call MySQL stored procedure with parameter in Google App Script?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, google-apps-script

I am trying to call MySQL stored procedure with a parameter and store the fetched data into result set.

1. How do I call the stored procedure using the parameter
2. How do I fetch the result and store inside Result Set

I am using external database MySQL, server: MariaDB .

```js
var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('<connection string>');
  
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    
  var callstoredprocedure = "SET @p0='"+currentUser+"'; CALL DCCwebApp_getAllApprovedDocument (@p0);";
  var mysqlquery = conn.prepareStatement(callstoredprocedure);
  
  
  var resultSet = mysqlquery.executeUpdate();
  var row = 1; 
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) { 
      Logger.log(resultSet.getString(col + 1));
    }
    row++;
  }
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
```

I am expecting a result set after i call the stored procedure using parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('<connection string>');

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();

  var callstoredprocedure = "{call DCCwebApp_getAllApprovedDocument(?)}";
  var mysqlquery = conn.prepareStatement(callstoredprocedure);

  mysqlquery.setString(1, currentUser);

  var resultSet = mysqlquery.executeQuery();
```